# web2py - allow external access - how?

Tags: python, web2py

I want to start a web2py server so that it can be accessed externally to the hosting server.

I've read this  http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03

> By default, web2py runs its web server on 127.0.0.1:8000 (port 8000 on
>   localhost), but you can run it on any available IP address and port.
>   You can query the IP address of your network interface by opening a
>   command line and typing ipconfig on Windows or ifconfig on OS X and
>   Linux. From now on we assume web2py is running on localhost
>   (127.0.0.1:8000). **Use 0.0.0.0:80 to run web2py publicly on any of your
>   network interfaces**.

but I can't find how to "Use 0.0.0.0:80" ? There doesn't seem to be a command line argument which would do that.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**: I should say the server in question does not have a GUI - I'm aware there's some sort GUI based admin facilties for web2py but that's out of the question here.

---

**EDIT2**: Just in case this is not clear (and on the offchance it makes any difference - which I doubt) I'm running the server like this :

```
sudo python web2py.py
```

*not* via wsgi/apache or the like.

Comment: You'll need root (sudo) to bind to port 80 for sure. That said, port 8000 should be fine for dev work, and you shouldn't be using the build-in server for production anyway

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
python web2py.py --ip 0.0.0.0
```

just works fine but the log message will point you to an invalid address:

```
please visit:
    http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

alternatively you can use ethernet interface ip but it will not listen also on localhost

Answer (score 4):

What may help you is the fact that you can select the public ip when the server gui pops up asking for the admin password.

Comment: the server does not need the guy, I started it without tkinter

Answer (score -2):

do the following in a terminal

```
install ufw with apt
add 8000 to firwall.
ufw allow 8000/tcp
ufw allow 8000/tcp
```

navigate to where your downloaded web2py is and cd web2py

use nano serverstartup.sh and add the line bellow

```
python2.7 web2py.py -a 'Server admin passwrod' -c server.crt -k server.key -i your device IP address -p 8000
```

change the the server admin password to any password of your choice.

```
chmod +x serverstartup.sh

run ./serverstartup.sh in your terminal
```

that is it. you can stop the server by holding control and c key on your keboard.